# How can I speed up this nested for loop?

Tags: python, loops

```
for step2 in pointsgood:

    quality = []
    for step3 in pointsgood:
        if step2.x == step3.x and step2.y == step3.y:
            pass
        else:
            propag = get_prop_loss(step2.y,step2.x,step3.y,step3.x)

            if propag >= 125:
                quality.append(False)
            else:
                quality.append(True)
    percentage.append(sum(quality)/len(quality))
```

I am making a script to evaluate a radio signal in a designated area. pointsgood is a list of points (Geoseries) that make a grid over a polygon I am interested in. I am comparing each point to the rest of the points and finding the propagation loss (using get_prop_loss function), then finding the percentage of all propagation losses that are less than 125. I am interested in which point has the best coverage.

How can I make this more efficient? I'm looking at 3 days to analyze ~5000 points right now. I have started looking into multiprocessing and multithreading, is that a good direction to go?

Comment: What is `quality` but an array of zeroes and ones? Replace that with two counters instead.

Comment: Your bottleneck is not in this code.  How long does `get_prop_loss` take?  You're calling it 25 million times.  Isn't there a way to compute this analytically, rather than exhaustively?

Comment: get_prop_loss is pretty slow, it find an elevation profile between points a and b and uses the itmlogic package to find propagation loss.

Comment: Can you memoize (cache) the slow method `get_prop_loss`?

Comment: If `get_prop_loss` really really long, you should use **multiprocessing** to things up (you may be interested in [this small article](https://medium.com/contentsquare-engineering-blog/multithreading-vs-multiprocessing-in-python-ece023ad55a)) Second, you should compare *area* and *point-to-point* modes: chances are that area mode can calculate once and be used repeatedly. Third, if this task is performance-critical, consider rewriting it in a more low-level language, like C.

Comment: I looked into memoizing..... What is the best way to do this? Most examples show a function with a single input but in this case i have 4 inputs, and the repeating cases would have the start and stop coordinates swapped so I don't think this would register as a repeated calculation

Comment: Look into using numpy instead of lists and loops.

Comment: Oh, there's another solution, maybe most simple: you can prepare data, save it to disk and then use [this](https://github.com/NTIA/itm) in command-line mode. The trick is to use `xargs -n 1 -P [cores]` to run in parallel.